# Oven resistance short circuits

Tags: electrical, oven

After some water damage in the oven we have at home, whenever we turn the oven on a program and the resistances start heating up, it short circuits and cuts power.
After some investigation with my multi-meter I tested :

- The top grill resistance

  - Tested if the current goes through and it's fine
  - And the grill with the ground cable and it's fine too

The bottom grill works current goes through but when testing with the ground there is indeed a short circuit

So we're leaving the oven open to try to let it dry a little bit
But is there something else I should check ?
Since the bottom resistance is working in itself I don't think changing it would solve the issue would it

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What voltage are you resistance testing at?  To do a meaningful test on a 240V element you would need to do your resistance test at double that, or 480V.

Comment: So when I mean testing the resistance all I did was take my multi-meter, set it on 200 ohms and see that it fits within the 20-50 ohms range

Comment: Yeah, that won't give you a complete test.  Very often, insulation breakdown occurs above a particular voltage (similar to how VBO devices work) so you need to test at a high voltage.

Comment: So i just set the multi-meter on voltage ?

Comment: Random cheapie DVMs can't test at such a high voltage, you'd need a megger.  Honestly I would look for flash damage.  Causing an instant trip on a 40-50A breaker means 200-500A instant flow, and that's gonna leave a mark.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of flash damage ? Like a description or a photo ?